# issues while parsing Dateformat, need to change this method to accept nulls as well

Tags: java, spring, validation, methods, xml-parsing

what am i doing wrong here, currently xml node in request file coming in, the value 01/22/2020 had to be populated.testers are running new test cases and not populating and it throws an exception.
how can i work to accept empty string.

ParseException: Unparseable date:"".

at java.text.DateFormat.parse

```
           if(stringDate!=null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a check for empty also. If it is empty then formatter will not be able to parse it.

```
if (stringDate != null && !stringDate.isEmpty()) {
    if (stringDate.contains("-")) {
        format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    } else if (stringDate.contains("/")) {
        format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return formatter.parse(stringDate);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of if(stringDate!=null) use StringUtils.isEmpty()